# Finding nearest date to today in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

My query returns results similar to this.

```
id        date
510010    12/09/2013
510010    10/09/2013
510010    05/09/2013
510010    14/09/2013
510012    14/09/2013
510012    10/09/2013
```

Is there a way that I can make my query only select the date nearest todays date for each distinct id?

Expected outcome.

```
510010    12/09/2013
510010    10/09/2013
510012    10/09/2013
```

Thanks, 
Chris

Comment: it should return both if they are equally far apart.

Comment: Does this clear it up for you? If not then yes both dates under the same ID(two rows).

Comment: Sorry to give that impression however I did think you were unclear about what I was asking hence why I asked if I had covered everything your needed to know. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table named [YourTable] with the data...

```
id      date
------  ----------
510010  2013-09-12
510010  2013-09-10
510010  2013-09-05
510010  2013-09-14
510012  2013-09-14
510012  2013-09-10
```

...then you can create a saved query named [CalculateDaysAway] in Access...

```
SELECT 
    [id], 
    [date], 
    Abs(DateDiff("d", [date], Date()) AS DaysAway 
FROM YourTable
```

...which (when run on 2013-09-11) returns

```
id      date        DaysAway
------  ----------  --------
510010  2013-09-12  1
510010  2013-09-10  1
510010  2013-09-05  6
510010  2013-09-14  3
510012  2013-09-14  3
510012  2013-09-10  1
```

Now you can use that query as a basis for the query to return the closest date(s)...

```
SELECT 
    CalculateDaysAway.[id], 
    CalculateDaysAway.[date]
FROM 
    CalculateDaysAway
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            [id], 
            MIN(DaysAway) AS MinOfDaysAway
        FROM CalculateDaysAway
        GROUP BY [id]
    ) AS MinDays
        ON CalculateDaysAway.[id] = MinDays.[id]
            AND CalculateDaysAway.DaysAway = MinDays.MinOfDaysAway
```

...which (when run on 2013-09-11) returns

```
id      date
------  ----------
510010  2013-09-12
510010  2013-09-10
510012  2013-09-10
```