# Query for Nearest Dates, along with respective values

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I am fairly new to access and have taken the lynda online courses on queries, yet I still cannot figure out this problem. I currently have a query that returns something like the following information from 2 different relational tables. Access actually returns all possible combinations of date1 and date2 along with the associated values, but I've omitted the other results for the sake of brevity.

```
ID        date1         date2         Abs(date1-date2)   Date1 Lab Value
510010    12/09/2013    12/10/2013    1                  6
510010    10/09/2013    12/09/2013    60                 12
510010    11/09/2013    09/10/2013    61                 5
510010    03/09/2013    03/15/2013    6                  4
510012    06/09/2013    06/09/2013    0                  4
510012    03/25/2013    03/15/2013    10                 1
```

My goal is to have the query return unique record IDs with the smallest (minimum) difference between date 1 and date 2 (Abs(date1-date2)), along with all the respective field values (id, date1, date2, date1 lab value).

Expected Output:

```
ID        date1         date2         Abs(date1-date2)   Date1 Lab Value
510010    12/09/2013    12/10/2013    1                  6
510012    06/09/2013    06/09/2013    0                  4
```

This problem is very similar to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743599/finding-nearest-date-to-today-in-access-2013); however I was wondering if the query can be done exclusively through design view using aggregate queries and the criteria field.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where does [Date1 Lab Value] come from?  Is it an existing field?  Please post the original SQL from your query.  The criteria in June7's answer can technically be entered into the query designer, but there may be a more efficient way of selecting the Minimum difference if all the other fields are compatible.

Comment: SELECT Patients_t.ID, PSA_t.Date1, MRI_t.Date2, PSA_t.[Date1 Lab Value]
FROM (Patients_t INNER JOIN PSA_t ON Patients_t.PatientID = PSA_t.PatientID) INNER JOIN MRI_t ON Patients_t.PatientID = MRI_t.PatientID;

edit: There are 3 tables. "Table1" contains [ID]; "Table2" contains [Date1] and [Date1 Lab Value]; "Table3" Contains [Date2].

I could not get June7's method working..I keep getting a syntax error

Comment: Since it appears that you're new to posting here, it is worth editing the question to provide updated code and clean up the details.  I suggest editing the question text to correct "2" to "3" tables and adding the query text along with your explanation of the fields.  In your case it is important to see these details, because there was the possibility of doing this with a single query but because [Date 1 Lab Value] comes from one of the 3 joined tables, it is not possible to select that value with a simple, single aggregate query.

Comment: Thank you! You're solution below makes a ton of sense and it's helped me understand why "it's important to see these details." I will attempt your method on my data and I will also try June7's answer; I think it'll be good practice for understanding how querying with multiple tables works. Lastly, I'll update/edit my question to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post states that you want "unique record IDs", but unless you provide more details about the data or further selection criteria, it is still possible that June7's answer will return multiple rows for the same ID if more than one row has the same minimum date difference.

I'll guess that June7's query is not working for you because "Dataset" in your case is a multi-table join.  Instead, you need to first save your initial query and then apply June7's hint to the first query:

Query1:

```
SELECT Patients_t.ProstateID AS ID, PSA_t.PSA_Date AS [Date 1], MRI_t.MRI_Date AS [Date 2],
    PSA_t.PSa_Total AS [Date 1 Lab Data], Abs([PSA_date]-[MRI_Date]) AS Diff
FROM (Patients_t INNER JOIN PSA_t ON Patients_t.PatientID = PSA_t.PatientID)
    INNER JOIN MRI_t ON Patients_t.PatientID = MRI_t.PatientID
```

Query2:

```
SELECT ID, [Date 1], [Date 2], [Date 1 Lab Data], Diff
FROM Query1
WHERE (Query1.Diff = DMin("[Diff]","Query1","ID=" & [ID]))
```

The following alternative approach may be more efficient than using Domain Aggregate functions (i.e. DMin) and may be easier to apply other criteria in the case that you must absolutely limit the results to unique ID's as you stated.  Don't let the multiple queries of this approach fool you into thinking that the Domain Aggregate functions are better since they look "shorter and cleaner".  While use of DMin can be entered in the designer as you also requested, the following set of aggregate queries can also be created using only the designer.  I of course post the SQL since it is easier to post than showing a bunch of Designer screenshots for each step.

For example, to ensure uniqueness in the ID, suppose that we limit not only the difference between the dates, but then select the maximum [Date 2] when there are multiple matches to the first criteria.  (But this still only assumes that [Date 2] dates will be unique which might not be true. In the event that NO data guarantees unique records, you can use grouping and the further aggregate functions (e.g. MIN, MAX, LAST, FIRST) on the final query to ensure unique IDs but you must take care that the selected Date 1 value still corresponds to the Date 1 Lab value.)

Start with the same Query1:

Query 3A - get minimum date differences:

```
SELECT ID, Min(Query1.Diff) AS [Min Diff]
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.ID
```

Query 3B - apply original criteria AND get maximum Date 2 for each match:

```
SELECT ID, [Min Diff], Max(Query1.[Date 2]) AS [Max Date 2]
FROM Query3a INNER JOIN Query1
    ON (Query3a.ID = Query1.ID) AND (Query3a.[Min Diff] = Query1.Diff)
GROUP BY ID, [Min Diff]
```

Query 4 - Apply final selection:

```
SELECT Query1.*
FROM Query3B INNER JOIN Query1
    ON (Query3B.[Max Date 2] = Query1.[Date 2])
    AND (Query3B.[Min Diff] = Query1.Diff) AND (Query3B.ID = Query1.ID);
```

Comment: Now that I finished my answer, I realize that the other question you linked to probably did answer the question.  The only difference is that it used a nested query.  But as I show in my answer, you can always take a nested query and save it separately and then refer to it in another query... using the query designer without editing the SQL.

Comment: So I have encountered one small hitch in the DMin Statement... Access is taking issue to the Criteria parameter. I get an error saying "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[ID]=prostate_id 000020'."... Any suggestions - I've used the code that you and June7 provided verbatim. Also, I'll try your second method and report back.

Comment: Your 2nd method worked flawlessly! I'm starting to understand how to join tables in my favor for performing queries. The issue is that the first method may seem more intuitive to my "novice" colleagues, so it would be awesome if we could resolve the Syntax Error.

Comment: Realize that Domain Aggregate Functions like DMin (or any VBA function for that matter) do not know about the query which calls them--they are not equivalent to the SQL aggregate functions--so the value and criteria string (1st and 3rd parameters) that you pass to it must only contain fields which are valid to the "domain" string (the 2nd parameter, either a table or query name) and any reference to a query field must be changed to the value for each row of the query.  In other words, the parameter expression `"ID=" & [ID]` will evaluate as `"ID=5"` or `"ID=39"`, for example.

Comment: From the text of your error message, it looks like your criteria parameter is not identical to June7's example.   '[ID]=prostate_id 000020'  indicates that the parameter contains both the string literal AND a reference to the query field.  Do you have something like `"[ID]=prostate_id " & [prostate_id]`?

Comment: I think I understand, but I don't see why the error is occurring. Here are my two Queries [imgur link](http://imgur.com/a/DFoiP).. I don't know if it matters, but I should note that ID: [Prostate ID] is a string variable and all of the values in that column are "prostate_id ######", where the #'s are numbers. Thank you for your help, I've learned a lot from your responses.

Comment: Ahh! Details, details! I was assuming that the ID field was a number.  In MS Access SQL a string literal can be delimited with either double or single quotes.  Since you are already using double quotes to pass string values to DMin, you must use single quotes to delimit the [Prostrate ID] value:  `"ID='" & [ID] & "'"`.  This will produce `ID='prostate_id ######'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
SELECT ID, Date1, Date2, Date1_LabValue, Abs([Date1]-[Date2]) AS Diff
FROM Dataset
WHERE (((Abs([Date1]-[Date2]))=DMin("Abs([Date1]-[Date2])","Dataset","ID=" & [ID])));
```

"Dataset" is whatever table or query with the data shown in your example, except for the date difference calculated field. I calc that here.